# Why after installing new Bigbluebutton on VMware, it shows empty blue screen?

Tags: ssl, installation, vmware, bigbluebutton

I installed a new fresh Bigbluebutton server on VMware without domain and SSL, after installing bbb-demo when I logged in, it showed an empty blue screen. In the browser console this exception was written:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'ondevicechange' of undefined
```

The last time when I face a similar situation, I try to set a self-signed SSL but it just makes lots of problems and it didn't work.

How I could solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've solved the problem. In this [address](https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bbb-install/issues/263) ffdixon(product manager for BigBlueButton) said:

> We need to update the docs -- you must setup an SSL certificate for BigBlueButton or it won't load. If you see "Not Secure" on your browser URL, BigBlueButton will not load.

I didn't have any valid IP or domain for my VM, So I created a valid SSL with one other domain(not belong to my VMware) and setup bbb to use SSL based on this [article](https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/2.2/install.html#configure-ssl-on-your-bigbluebutton-server).Then set /etc/host to redirect SSL domain name to my local IP.